# “Request contains an invalid argument. Types should be same across locales. Expected: [$entityName]. Actual: [].”

Tags: dialogflow-es

Whenever I try to test my google assistant integration, I get the title error message.
Below is a pic of what the error message looks like.

[image: error message in the wild]

The only way I can get rid of this message is to delete all of my entities.
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Consider putting the text of your message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my agent. The problem was some entities were created in one language (french), and other entities in another language (english).
To solve the problem, I removed the english language of my agent.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. I create my entity in English, then I tried to enable German on the same agent. My solution is: add synonyms to the entity under "de" (German language) mode.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! As explained in [answer], *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*. This answer would benefit from you [edit]ing it to include an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I cam across this when I was trying to test my script on Simulator.
Below are the steps I followed:

1. Clicked on `Integrations` from the left panel.
2. On the dialog box that appeared, if I clicked on Test I was facing this issue. So I clicked on "`Manage Assistant App`". This opened a new window named "`Actions on Google`" Refer the below image.
   [image: Google Assistant dialog box]
3. Here I could easily access the `Simulator` and other functionalities from the left panel.

I hope this helps!!!